# Trace of map & matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $1\leq m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field.
For $a\in M_m(\mathbb{K})$ we consider the map $\mu_a$ that is defined by $$\mu_a: \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}, \ c\mapsto ac$$

I want to show that $trace(\mu_a)=n\cdot trace(a)$ .

I have done the following:

Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalues of $\mu_a$ then we have that $\mu_a(c)=\lambda c$.

From $\mu_a(c)=\lambda c$ we get $ac=\lambda c$.

So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mu_a$, tthere is a non-zero $c\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ with $\mu_a(c)=\lambda c$.

The columns of $c$ are all eigenvectors of $a$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

The matrix $c$ has $n$ columns.

So for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $a$ there are $n$ eigenvectors, so the multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $n$.

The trace of a matrix is the sum of teh eigenvalues considering the multiplicity.

Since each eigenvalue of $\mu_a$ has a multiplicity of $n$, it follows that $\text{trace}(\mu_a)=\sum_i n\cdot \lambda_i=n\cdot \sum_i\lambda $.

Since $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $a$, it follows that $\text{trace}(a)=\sum_i\lambda_i$.

Therefore we get $\text{trace}(\mu_a)=n\cdot \text{trace}(a)$.

Is everything correct?

Comment: You should spell out why the multiplicity of $\lambda$ for $\mu_a$ is $n$.

Comment: Isn't it because there are $n$ eigenvectors for each $\lambda$ ? @Berci

Comment: Which eigenvectors do you have in mind? Also, what if $a$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: I thought the following: We take an eigenvalue of $\mu_a$, say $\lambda$ then we get $\mu_a(c)=\lambda c\Rightarrow ac=\lambda c$. From the last equation we get that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue also for $a$. $c$ is a matrix and so the columns of $c$ are the eigenvectors that correspond to $a$. Is the way I am thinking correct? @Berci

Comment: If you have already defined the tensor product and established its properties, then it would be enough to note that we can identify $\mu_a$ with the map $(a \otimes \operatorname{id})$ over $\Bbb K^m \otimes \Bbb K^n$

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct in the case that $a$ is diagonalizable. If $a$ is not diagonalizable, it suffices to show that the dimension of the generalized eigenspace of $\mu_a$ associated with $\lambda$ is $n$ times the dimension of the generalized eigenspace of $a$ associated with $\lambda$.

We can show this in turn by noting that this generalized eigenspace of $a$ is $\ker(a - \lambda I)^m$, and
$$
(\mu_a - \lambda I)^k = \mu_{(a - \lambda I)^k}.
$$

Comment: Is the trace equal to the dimension of eigenspace? Could you explain to me also the second part? Why is the generalized eigenspace of $a$ the $\ker(a - \lambda I)^m$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues including algebraic multiplicity, so it's the sum of all eigenvalues multiplied by the dimension of their respective generalized eigenpsaces. As for your second question that's a fairly standard characterization of generalized eigenspaces that you should be able to find in any book that covers Jordan canonical form

Comment: What do you mean by $(\mu_a - \lambda I)^k = \mu_{(a - \lambda I)^k}.$ ?

Comment: And why does this equation hold?

Comment: @MaryStar I mean that $(\mu_a - \lambda I)^k(c)$ will be equal to $(a - \lambda I)^k c$. This is just a consequence of the definition of $\mu_a$.

Comment: Is it because $mu_a$ is homogeneous? $$(\mu_a-\lambda I)^k(c)=(\mu_a(c)-\lambda Ic)^k=(ac-\lambda Ic)^k=(a-\lambda I)^kc$$ Or is that wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar The expression $(\mu_a(c)-\lambda Ic)^k$ is not necessarily defined, and is not equal to what we want when it is defined.

Comment: @MaryStar Can you show that the map $a \mapsto \mu_a$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: Ok! We have that $\mu_a(c_1+c_2)=ac_1+ac_2=\mu_a(c_1)+\mu_a(c_2)$ and $\mu_a(c_1c_2)=ac_1c_2$ Do we multiply here with $a^{-1}a$ to get the missing $a$ ?

Comment: For the third condition: $\mu_a(I_n)=aI_n$. So do we take here $a$ to be the unit matrix?

Comment: @MaryStar Your steps would be useful if we wanted to show that $c \mapsto \mu_a(c)$ is a homomorphism, but this is not what we want to show, nor is it true. I am asking you to show that $a \mapsto \mu_a$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: So we have to show that $\mu_{a_1+a_2}=\mu_{a_1}+\mu_{a_2}$, $\mu_{a_1a_2}=\mu_{a_1}\mu_{a_2}$ and $\mu_{I_n}=I_n$, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

With a matrix representation for $\mu_a$ you may compute the trace somewhat simpler as the sum of its diagonal elements, without having to worry about diagonalising the map. To get such a representation you may use the trick of introducing a $\delta$ (over indices) and rewrite in the following index form (like a disguised variant of the comment of @Omnomnomnom):  $$(\mu_a(c))_{ij}= \sum_{k} a_{ik}c_{kj} = \sum_k\sum_l a_{ik}\delta_{jl} c_{kl} = \sum_{k,l} M_{ij,kl} c_{kl}.$$
Here $M_{ij,kl}= a_{ik} \delta_{jl}$ is just a 'normal' $mn \times mn$ matrix and the trace is given by $${\rm tr\;} \mu_a = {\rm tr\;} M = \sum_{ij} M_{ij,ij} = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ii}\delta_{jj} = {\rm tr\; } a  \times n.$$